# In the Hypothesis library for Python, why does the text() strategy cause custom strategies to retry?

Tags: python, hypothesis-test, python-hypothesis, property-based-testing

I have a custom strategy built using `composite` that draws from `text` strategy internally.

Debugging another error (`FailedHealthCheck.data_too_large`) I realized that drawing from the `text` strategy can cause my composite strategy to be invoked roughly twice as often as expected.

I was able to reproduce the following minimal example:

```py
@hypothesis.strategies.composite
def my_custom_strategy(draw, n):
    """Strategy to generate lists of N strings"""

    trace("a")
    value = [draw(hypothesis.strategies.text(max_size=256)) for _ in range(n)]
    trace("b")
    return value


@given(my_custom_strategy(100))
def test_my_custom_strategy(value):
    assert len(value) == 100
    assert all(isinstance(v, str) for v in value)
```

In this scenario, `trace("a")` was invoked 206 times, whereas `trace("b")` was only invoked 100 times. These numbers are consistent across runs.

More problematic, the gap increases the more times I call text(), and super-linearly. When `n=200`, `trace("a")` is called 305 times. `n=400`, 984 times. `n=500` or greater, the test reliably pauses and then completes after the 11th iteration (with only 11 iterations, instead of 100!)

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're running into the maximum entropy (about 8K) used to generate Hypothesis examples, if some of the strings you generate happen to be quite long.  Setting a reasonable `max_size` in the text strategy would help, if I'm right.

As a more general tip, [shrinking can be more efficient](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/master/guides/strategies-that-shrink.rst#keep-things-local) if you use the `lists()` strategy (or another collections strategy) rather than picking an integer and then that many elements.  This is not a subtle problem though; if you haven't already noticed you don't need to do anything!

Comment: I did a few tests, and this does appear to be correct. Interestingly, excluding `Phase.target` increases the amount of successful attempts from ~46% to 99%. Apparently that phases reduces the amount of available entropy, even without any explicit calls to `target`?